# Why is component rendering before this.setState() has finished setting the state?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am building my first react native app. I am using Firebase, Redux, and React Native to build my app.

I am using a thunk to fetch data from my database and I want to set my component's local state with that data.

When I console.log(this.props.room) in the render function I can see the data from my database but it's not being added to the local state in componentDidMount(), so I know my thunk and the backend is working properly.

I think my component is rendering before my local state is set in the componentDidMount function. Is there a way to prevent it from rendering while this.setState() is running? My code is below. Or is there another reason this.setState isn't working?

````
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

import { submitIdea, getRoom } from '../redux/reducers/rooms/actions'
class RoomScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Undecided!'
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentUser: '',
      submittedIdea: false,
      currentUserIdea: '',
      roomName: '',
      ownerName: '',
      peopleAndIdeas: [],
      prompt: '',
      room: {}
    }
    this.handleIdeaSubmit = this.handleIdeaSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleIdeaSubmit() {
    const { user, roomName } = this.props.navigation.state.params
    this.setState({ submittedIdea: true })
    this.props.submitIdea(user, this.state.userIdea, roomName)
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { user, roomName } = this.props.navigation.state.params
    await this.props.getRoom(roomName)
    this.setState({
      room: this.props.room
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
          <View>
            <Text>Room name: {this.state.room.name}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>This room was created by: {this.state.room.owner}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>What are we deciding? {this.state.room.prompt}</Text>
          </View>

          {/* checking whether or not the user has submitted an idea and altering the view */}

          {!this.state.submittedIdea ?

            <View style={styles.container}>
              <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ userIdea: text })}
                value={this.state.createRoomName}
                placeholder="Enter your idea."
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.handleIdeaSubmit}
              >
                <Text> Submit Idea. </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> :
            <View>
              <Text>Your idea was: {this.props.userIdea}</Text>
            </View>
          }

          <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
            <Text>IDEAS</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>USERS</Text>
          </View>

        </ScrollView>
      </View >
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  room: state.room.room
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getRoom: (roomName) => dispatch(getRoom(roomName)),
  submitIdea: (user, idea, roomName) => dispatch(submitIdea(user, idea, roomName))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoomScreen)```
````

Answer (score 2):

This is because setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

So you can do something like this,

```
this.setState({foo: 'bar'}, () => { 
// Do something here. 
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize that setState was async. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! So u got the idea you can await for this.setState()

Answer (score 0):

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const { user, roomName } = this.props.navigation.state.params
  await this.props.getRoom(roomName)
  this.setState({
    room: this.props.room
  })
}
```

You don't have to use local state in this case.

```
 render() {
 const {room: {name}} = this.props;

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
      <View>
        <Text>Room name: {name}</Text>
      </View>
   </ScrollView>
  </View>
  )
 }
```

Here since you are using redux (global state), you don't have to add it in your local state. You can directly access the value of the room from the props.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Unsure why I was trying to use local state.